# Hardhat chainID 31337 not changed to 1337 of Metamask localhost

Tags: metamask, hardhat

I tried to use 1337 as chainID on Hardhat to match metamask localhost 8545.
[image]

My hardhat.config.js have already included 1337 chainID for hardhat as below.

> ```
> module.exports = {
>   solidity: "0.8.17",
>   networks: {
>     hardhat: {
>       chainId: 1337
>     }
>   }
> };
> ```

As you can see above, I set chainId as 1337, but it didn't work and I got the below error when I try to use the contract's setGreeting function in frontend.

> ```
> async function setGreeting() {
>     if (!greeting) return
>     if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
>       await requestAccount()
>       const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
>       const signer = provider.getSigner()
>       const contract = new ethers.Contract(greeterAddress, Greeter.abi, signer)
>       const transaction = await contract.setGreeting(greeting)
>       await transaction.wait()
>       fetchGreeting()
>     }
>   }
> ```

The error is below.
[image]

Can you please inform me how to use 1337 instead of 31337 on Hardhat?

Comment: What does your hardhat chain say when you start it? Does it show the right ID?

Comment: Hardhat default chainId is just 31337, and I want to change it to 1337 to match metamask.

Answer (score 0):

don't force to use 1337 id. Just add another network using chain id 31337.

Click fabcon -> settings -> networks -> add network

[image]